# Opening a pre-existing file located at mobile storage (Android app using android Studio )

Tags: android-studio

I want to open a text file which is in my phone storage at some path and I want to select its content without opening a folder instead specifying path of it.
I have already started coding of it, just strucked at specifying the path of file , I am using java in android studio.

Please help me with this.

I am expecting an answer in which there is detail about how exactly to give the path of file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.